# Project Linking and Compiling files

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

I want to start building a project and I have the following folder structure:

```
lib
|---class1.cpp
|---class1.hpp
src
|---main.cpp
```

I have the MinGW compiler and I don't know how to compile all `.cpp` files.  I know the command `g++ *.cpp -o main` for compiling all the files, but works only for files in the same folder.

Should I move all my files to the `src` folder? Should I change the project structure?
Also, I'm really doubtful if I should use CMake or not.

FINAL:
I decided to go with CMake which made my life easier.

Comment: Just list the files - `g++ src/main.cpp lib/class1.cpp -o main`. Maybe some bash wizards could come up with glob that goes recursively. CMake might be an overkill, but if you learn to use it on small projects, it will only benefit you.

Comment: ***Should I change the project structure?*** Your structure will not make the building that much more difficult if that is the question. I use several more layers of folders in my projects but my projects have hundreds of source files with multiple libraries and utility programs.

Comment: For projects that simple I usually just use a [Makefile](https://makefiletutorial.com/), in which you can list all you source (or find them if you're lazy), and call `g++` with them. This avoids having to retype everything each time you want to compile. `CMake` is also a great tool but probably not worth it for such a simple project.

Comment: CMake is much easier to use than make: unless you track who is including the .hpp files by hand, you'll miss some recompiles when you need them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a barebones project, your structure is fine. Just add the following CMakeLists.txt file to the root of your directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Given your project a descriptive name
project(cool_project)

# CHoose whatever standard you want here... 11, 14, 17, ...
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# The first entry is the name of the target (a.k.a. the executable that will be built)
# every entry after that should be the path to the cpp files that need to be built
add_executable(cool_exe src/main.cpp lib/class1.cpp)

# Tell the compiler where the header files are
target_link_libraries(cool_exe PRIVATE lib)
```

Your directory should now look like

```
CMakeLists.txt
lib
|---class1.cpp
|---class1.hpp
src
|---main.cpp
```

Then to build the project, you will typically

1. Make a folder where you build everything (often called `build`, but it's up to you). Now the directory looks like

   ```
    CMakeLists.txt
    lib
    |---class1.cpp
    |---class1.hpp
    src
    |---main.cpp
    build
   ```
2. Go into the build folder and on the command like, configure your project with the command `cmake ..` (just to reiterate... this needs to be done from inside the build folder).
3. Build your project with the `make` command (again from inside the build folder).

After that, you should have an executable called `cool_exe` in the build folder.